# Resize FastScroll alert dialog

Tags: android

I want to use FastScroll for my history list and use dates for sections, but alert dialog (that shows letters in contacts) does not stretch to fit text's size (i want to show there month and day).

How can I resize it?

Comment: Any progress? Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution.
We disable built-in Fastscroll feature and use [this](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/RingsExtended/src/com/example/android/rings_extended/FastScrollView.java) code with minor changes. Variable  mOverlaySize is responsible for size of section alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something as simple as using `setView` in the AlertDialog class? (Along with some edits to the .xml). First, I took info on `setView` from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).

```
public void setView (View view, int viewSpacingLeft, int viewSpacingTop, int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom)

Set the view to display in that dialog, specifying the spacing to appear around that view.    
Parameters:
view    The view to show in the content area of the dialog
viewSpacingLeft Extra space to appear to the left of view
viewSpacingTop  Extra space to appear above view
viewSpacingRight    Extra space to appear to the right of view
viewSpacingBottom   Extra space to appear below view
```

And here's some the SDK's sample code (AlertDialogSamples.java) which uses `setView`.

```
case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:
            // This example shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .create();
        }
        return null;
```

And finally, some of the xml file looks like it adds margins around the text (alert_dialog_text_entry.xml).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/username_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="@string/alert_dialog_username"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can this  be applied to the FastScroll? Sorry for late answer.